# How to debounce a retrofit reactive request in java?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm working on an android project that makes requests through retrofit using Rx-Java observable and subscribe.

However, in some interactions this request can be called multiple times  and I would like to only execute the last one in a predefined window of time (debounce).

I tried to apply the `debounce` operator directly to the observable, but it will not work because the code below is executed every time some interaction occurs:

```
mApi.getOnlineUsers()
    .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe(...)
```

I guess it should be created only one observable and every interaction it should "append" the execution to the same observable. But I am kind of new on Rx Java and don't know exactly what to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose you want to start an execution according to some trigger event.

```
Observable<Event> trigger = ... // e.g. button clicks
```

You can transform the trigger events to calls to your API like this:

```
trigger
    .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap(event -> mApi.getOnlineUsers())
    .subscribe(users -> showThemSomewhere(users));
```

Also, notice that the `debounce` operator will take the **last** occurrence within the time frame, but `throttlefirst` will take the **first**. You may want to use one or the other depending on your use case.

Comment: Good point, and you might as well consider using [PublishRelay](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay)