# rxandroid asks to run on ui thread even though it is subscribed on AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

Tags: android, rx-java

I have written a subscriber that will get triggered when google map's `OnCameraChangeListener` is triggered.

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<LatLng>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super LatLng> subscriber)
        {
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
            {
                mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(cameraPosition ->
                        subscriber.onNext(cameraPosition.target));
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<LatLng>empty())
            .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(position -> {
                if (position.latitude != 0 && position.longitude != 0)
                {
                    updateLocationMarker(position);
                }
            });
```

I am updating the location marker as below:

```
private void updateLocationMarker(LatLng center)
{
    locationMarkertext.setText("Lat:" + center.latitude + " Long:" + center.longitude);
    //locationMarkerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Even though my code says to run on `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` I get this error:

> Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Can some one please help me understand what is the problem with my approach

Comment: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/index.html?rx/exceptions/OnErrorNotImplementedException.html. May be you just need to handle the error in onError

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The operator `debounce` by default runs on the computation scheduler where it will deliver the events flowing through. You have to parameterize it with the main thread scheduler:

```
.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

In addition, depending on where you create your notification source, you may not need `observeOn` and `subscribeOn` at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. It works perfectly. Similar to the above situation I am trying to debounce a retrofit call. I read it in one of the SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269954/how-to-debounce-a-retrofit-reactive-request-in-java , Here, retrofit does not call the web service second time. I get an error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already executed. Can you please have a look at my gist https://gist.github.com/rakesh1988/f92a8fada282779f971e329e00323a76

Comment: I think I solved this issue. *call.enqueue* should be replaced with *call.clone()enqueue()*.... But the problem now is, I see there are multiple calls happening to my web server. i can see Timber.d("BRAVO!!!"); printing many times. Any pointers to resolve this issue?

Comment: Had the same issue with `delay` operator.
Fixed it by adding `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` as last parameter.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the main thread will be blocked for 1 sec?

Comment: No, a timed task is scheduled by the main thread that fires after 1 second. Until then, any other non-timed tasks on the main thread can execute at will.

Comment: awesome! the interesting part is that no matter if I added `observeOn` and/or `subscribeOn` but unless I passed `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` as third param to `delay` this would never work!

Comment: thank you, I was having the same issue using the `buffer` operator!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not the correct way to do it. The correct was is to place `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` **after** `debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`. So your code becomes:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<LatLng>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super LatLng> subscriber)
        {
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
            {
                mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(cameraPosition ->
                        subscriber.onNext(cameraPosition.target));
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<LatLng>empty())
            .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(position -> {
                if (position.latitude != 0 && position.longitude != 0)
                {
                    updateLocationMarker(position);
                }
            });
```

Debounce should be run on the `ComputationScheduler` rather than the main thread.

Comment: Funny, you are telling that top RxJava library contributor have proposed incorrect way to change thread after the debounce operation.

Comment: Hmm seems that way :) @akarnokd Please have a look and tell where I'm mistaken.

Comment: This works for me, I think the point is to deliver the event to main thread