# Retrofit calls being made multiple times when debounce with a subject

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I followed this link *[How to debounce a retrofit reactive request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269954/how-to-debounce-a-retrofit-reactive-request-in-java)* to debounce a retrofit reactive request.
Below is my piece of code

```
//i declare the subject globally
PublishSubject<Call<List<Response>>> subject = PublishSubject.create();

//this is how i call retrofit
private void updateMarkers(LatLng center)
{
    subject.onNext(new APIHelper().
                GetNearByLocations("auth_key", center.latitude, center.longitude, urgency));

    subject.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(call -> {
                    call.clone().enqueue(new Callback<List<Response>>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<List<Response>> call, Response<List<Response>> response)
                        {
                             Timber.d("BRAVO!!!");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<List<Response>> call, Throwable t)
                        {
                            Timber.d("someone's gonna get hurt real bad!!!");
                        }
                    });

                });
  }
```

This is what is happening. Every time updateMarkers() method is called, retrofit creates a new call.clone() and the number of times it calls my back end increases by 1 every time. I also tried to declare APIHelper() globally and use the same object to make my back end call. But, the result is same. Please help me with some pointers to solve this issue.

Comment: move the subject.debounce in another method, in order to subscribe once in your application (and not each time you calling updateMakers)

Comment: I moved it to onCreate() so that the subject.debounce method is registered. Is there a better place I can move it to?

Comment: onResume ? by the way, why your Retrofit call return a Call ? can't you return directlry a Observable ? subject.debonce(1, SECONDS).flatMap(latLg -> api.getNearbyLocation(latLg.latitude, latLg.longitude)).subscribe();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the actual case, you add a subscriber each time `updateMarkers` is called.

In order to achieve what you wants, you'll have to move the creation of your Observable in another method, for example `onResume` or `onCreate` :

```
//i declare the subject globally
PublishSubject<Call<List<Response>>> subject = PublishSubject.create();

private void updateMarkers(LatLng center)
{
    subject.onNext(new APIHelper().
            GetNearByLocations("auth_key", center.latitude, center.longitude, urgency));

}

@Override
public void onResume(Context ctx) {


       subject.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(call -> {
                call.clone().enqueue(new Callback<List<Response>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Response>> call, Response<List<Response>> response)
                    {
                         Timber.d("BRAVO!!!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Response>> call, Throwable t)
                    {
                        Timber.d("someone's gonna get hurt real bad!!!");
                    }
                });

            });
}
```

Please note that you can use Retrofit 2 with RxJava :

Your API :

```
 public interface MyApi {
            Observable<String> getNearByLocation(Double latitude, Double longitude);
 }
```

your Activity :

```
//i declare the subject globally
PublishSubject<LatLng> subject = PublishSubject.create();

private void updateMarkers(LatLng center)
{
    subject.onNext(center);
}

public void onCreate(Context ctx) {

       subject.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .flatMap(latLng -> api.getNearByLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude))
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(r -> Timber.d("BRAVO !"), e -> Timber.d("Problems")); 

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to write this. when I tried to use the observable way of solving, I bumped into network on main thread exception. I am surprised why I got that error even though I had subscribed on io thread. After trying various combinations, i can see that observeOn, subscribeOn and also the debounce method should be run on Schedulers.io(). is this expected? Also, my subject is not getting called the second time. is there some equivalent of call.cone() that I need to implement?

Comment: Also I have another doubt. In general case, I show progressbar when the call is made to my back end and I stop showing it when onResponse or onFailure is called. In this debounce case, I need to wait till my debounce time is elapsed and then start to show progressbar. Is there any way I can handle this situation?